# Filter across three tables using django ORM

Tags: django

> I have 3 django models, where the second has a foreign key to the first, and the third has a foreign key to the first. Like this:

```
    NewRegistration Model

    class NewRegistration(models.Model):
            registration_date = models.DateField()
            ward_no = models.ForeignKey(system_settings.models.Wardno)
            latitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=16, max_digits=30)
            longitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=16, max_digits=30)
            is_forwarded = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
    Landowner Model

    class Landowner(models.Model):
        lo_address_roadname_en = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
        reg = models.ForeignKey(NewRegistration)
```

```
    Application  model

    class Application(models.Model):
        building_storey = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
        reg = models.ForeignKey(NewRegistration)
```

> I want to count the data of application table on the basis of no_of_storey having  certain lo_address_roadname_en from Landowner model and certain  ward_no from NewRegistration Model and having certain registration_date  from NewRegistration Model
>   I have tried like this.

```
 building_storey = Application.objects.filter(reg__ward_no=ward_no).filter(reg__registration_date__gte=start_date,reg__registration_date__lte=end_date).values('building_storey').annotate(Count('building_storey'))
            context['building_storey'] = building_storey
```

> How can i filter from three tables? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
NewRegistration.objects.filter(
      registration_date__gt=${date},
      Landowner__lo_address_roadname_en=${lo_address_value},
      ward_no=${ward_no},
).values('Application__building_storey')
```

This is how you can filter values from 3 tables.